# Non Dictionary Value Value Enumerable

Tags: c#

I need to store a `<string, byte[]>` pair for creating zip files (I execute an asynchronous download function that returns the byte array of the file, and I get the file name from parsing the URL)

I have been using a dictionary up to this point for testing, but I knew eventually we'd need something else, as the file names are not unique.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I cannot for the life of me think of an Enumerable object collection which stores a non-unique `<TValue, TValue>` pair.

**Code Sample**

```
public async Task<ZipFile> CreateZipFormUrls(List<string> urlList)
{
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        var files = await ReturnFileDataAsync(urlList);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var e = zip.AddEntry(file.Key, file.Value);
        }

        return zip;
    }
}

async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReturnFileDataAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(async url => new
        {
            Key = Path.GetFileName(url),
            Value = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url),
        }));
        return results.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a `List<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>>`?

Comment: How are the filenames not unique? They have to be unique on the filesystem ...

Comment: Doesn't `KeyValuePair` enforce unique values as well? I'll run into the same issue I assume.

Comment: @Wesley No, `Dictionary` enforces uniqueness, The KVPs don't know about each other in a list.

Comment: @vcsjones: But unless they're actually meant to be keys, using KVP suggests an association which isn't actually present.

Comment: @clcto there could be /resources/files/presentation.pptx and /marketing/worlddomination/presentation.ppts, but once they're in the zip file they are both presentation.pptx

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough point, I heard that OP was using `Dictionary<K,V>`, and enumerating over it (which yields KVPs) so I went down the route of "A change that will work with least impact on the code" so the type returned by the enumerator would be the same.

Comment: @Wesley Seems like all you need is using *Lookup* instead of *Dictionary* `return results.ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);` (Of course return type of the method should be changed too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `List<Tuple<string, byte[]>>`... or personally I'd strongly consider creating a custom class for this - and then just have a list of them.

The advantage of using a custom class over `Tuple` is that you can then give the properties sensible names - and potentially add things like a method to return a `Stream` for the data.

I would *not* use `KeyValuePair` here unless the string really is meant to be a key. If the names aren't unique, they don't sound like keys to me.

Comment: I was worried about efficiency issues with a custom class. Any reason not to use the Tuple?

Comment: @Wesley Readability. Dealing with `Item1` and `Item2` is always less readable then a class property.

Comment: @Wesley: The code isn't as clear when you have `Item1` and `Item2` instead of (say) `Name` and `Content`. What *specific* efficiency issue are you concerned about?

Comment: @Wesley We can't possibly know what the appropriate data structure is from an efficient perspective without knowing how you're using the data structure.

Comment: @Wesley: So again, where do you expect inefficiency, and of what kind? I don't see any reason to assume that your own class would be less efficient than `Tuple<,>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is the back end of a Cross-Origin enabled cloud service that will be used frequently and with a great volume of files. Any efficiency gains are important. I may be over thinking this.

Comment: @Wesley: I would imagine that a single extra object per file is the *least* of your efficiency concerns. You should set *specific* performance requirements, write the simplest code to meet the functional requirements, and test the performance of that.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's possible. We won't know until we load it up and shoot it thousands of simultaneous requests where our stress points are.